# Unity Shadow Cascades cast a shadow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, shadow

I have a plane rendering a shadow onto a transparent plane as well as generating grid lines using a Universal Render Pipeline shader. At the edge of the shadow cascade boundries, I am seeing a jagged shadow following the geometry of the plane. The video below shows a plane at 10x scale with the shader applied. If we scale down the plane, it still has the jagged edges but again following the geometry size.

** Click image to view video **
[image]

[image: Lighting Settings]

[Quality Settings](https://github.com/Autodesk/synthesis/blob/f9e8675d9985f3444cb0b4659e59dcf355916203/engine/ProjectSettings/GraphicsSettings.asset)

We are using Ultra settings.

[Unity Shader](https://github.com/Autodesk/synthesis/blob/f9e8675d9985f3444cb0b4659e59dcf355916203/engine/Assets/Materials/Shaders/TransparentShadow.shader) Pretty work in progress, sorry.

Using Unity Editor `2022.3.2f`. Using Universal Render Pipeline `14.0.8`.

Currently on a MacbookPro M2 Pro; however, the same issue has been observed on a Razer 2020 with RTX 2070 on Windows.

Tried different scales of the plane, effect scaled with geometry size.
Originally observed with other shaders written in ShaderGraph (Version `14.0.8`).
We've also seen something potentially similar with more detailed meshes but presented itself as a kind of "quality range" that we initially ignored.

#### UPDATE

If I add a material that uses the `Universal Render Pipeline/Lit` shader, the jagged edges are no longer there.